# How does Apache Ignite supports partitioning?

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I am trying to experiment with data partition in Apache Ignite using .NET thin client.

In article https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes it's written that in partition mode "the overall data set is divided equally into partitions and all partitions are split equally between participating nodes". So I am expecting cache with 1000 records to be splitted beetween 3 Ignite nodes equally: 333(4) on each node. But when I start 3 instances of Ignite on local machine (using platforms\dotnet\bin\Apache.Ignite.exe) I can see only that 1000 records are replicated on all nodes: 1000 same records on each node. I tried to disable backups creation: 1000 records were created only on first node. Currently I use sequental Int32 values as cache key. But even when I ran LinqExample with colocated employes (with AffinityKey) data was't splitted beetween nodes.
I also tried to experiment with cache configuration:

```
var cacheConfiguration = new CacheClientConfiguration(_key, cacheEntity);
cacheConfiguration.CacheMode = CacheMode.Partitioned;
cacheConfiguration.Backups = 0;
cacheConfiguration.ReadFromBackup = false;
cacheConfiguration.RebalanceMode = CacheRebalanceMode.Sync;
cacheConfiguration.RebalanceOrder = 1;
cacheConfiguration.RebalanceThrottle = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
cacheConfiguration.RebalanceDelay = TimeSpan.Zero;
cacheConfiguration.RebalanceBatchSize = 1024;
var cache = _igniteClient.CreateCache<int, TEntityType>(cacheConfiguration).WithExpiryPolicy(_expiryPolicy);
```

Perhaps I don't understand the main concept of data partitioning implemented in Apache Ignite or Apache.Ignite.exe needs some additional configuration to support data partitioning. Execuse me if it's a simple question.

PS. I am using DBeaver to check amount of records on each node. 3 ignite instances by default uses ports 10800, 10801, 10802 for .NET client requests. So I am using localhost:10800, localhost:10801, localhost:10802 adresses in DBeaver.

Comment: How do you check the count of local records? You might try to use cache.LocalPeek. Also, a thin client will return all values from available nodes by default

Comment: You can use Web Console to check partition distribution between nodes.

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin, I am connecting to 3 ignite nodes with DBeaver (using 3 different ports: localhost:10800, localhost:8001, localhost:10802)

Comment: DBeaver utilizes the same thin client protocol underneath, so it's better to have a look at the GridGain WebConsole or to check it manually from a server-side or a thick client

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin thank you! I there more simple way to check count of records on each node without Web Console install?

Comment: I think the console script should support it as well. https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/control-script. The other option - try to run the query locally https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-api#local-execution

Comment: @OlegBevz regarding the WebConsole, it shouldn't be rocket science. Basically, you need to copy ignite-rest-http jar file from /optional libs to the classpath, visit https://console.gridgain.com/, download an agent (the second button from the bottom of the left panel) and run it. It's not mandatory to install it locally.

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin I've managed to lauch Web Console, but can't find information how many elements are stored on each node. On Monitoring Dashboard I can see only total number of elements in each cache. Data Replication tab is empty =(

Comment: I'll try to find it

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of entries per node, use included [Visor](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/visor-cmd) tool.

- Go to Ignite `bin` directory
- Start `ignitevisorcmd`
- Use `open` to connect to a cluster
- Type `cache -a`

Generated report will include table with node specifics:

```
Nodes for: person-cache-1(@c0)
+====================================================================================================================+
|       Node ID8(@), IP       | CPUs | Heap Used | CPU Load |   Up Time    |  Size (Primary / Backup)  | Hi/Mi/Rd/Wr |
+====================================================================================================================+
| 1F81F615(@n0),    127.0.0.1 | 12   | 10.26 %   | 0.00 %   | 00:08:15.394 | Total: 513 (513 / 0)      | Hi: 0       |
|                             |      |           |          |              |   Heap: 0 (0 / <n/a>)     | Mi: 0       |
|                             |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap: 513 (513 / 0) | Rd: 0       |
|                             |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap Memory: <n/a>  | Wr: 0       |
+-----------------------------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------+
| FBCF3B0F(@n1),    127.0.0.1 | 12   | 15.23 %   | 0.00 %   | 00:07:46.647 | Total: 486 (486 / 0)      | Hi: 0       |
|                             |      |           |          |              |   Heap: 0 (0 / <n/a>)     | Mi: 0       |
|                             |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap: 486 (486 / 0) | Rd: 0       |
|                             |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap Memory: <n/a>  | Wr: 0       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

According to Size(**Primary**/...) 999 entries are split between two nodes, with 513 entries on the first node and 486 on the second node.

Check "Primary" and not "Total"; "Total" is sum of primary entries and replicated entries from other nodes. Shown setup does not have replication, so it is equal to "Primary".

If a cluster had three nodes, and a cache had 2 replicas (so 3 copies in total), then the "Total" number on one node will be close to a total number of entries (as each node contains all entries, either as a primary node or backup node for two other nodes), "Primary" would be approximately 1/3 of the total and "Backup" would be 2/3.